# Horn clauses in Z3

Tags: z3

Z3 now supports solving for inductive invariants (implying a desired property) if the semantics of the program to analyze is given as Horn clauses.

The version in the `master` branch of the Z3 source code on [z3.codeplex.com](http://z3.codeplex.com) however does not support this feature. Since Z3 solves these Horn clauses problems by the PDR algorithm, which uses interpolation, I compiled instead the `interp` branch (`d8b31773b809`), which supports `(set-logic HORN)`.

As far as I understood, a Horn-clause problem is to be specified with unknown predicates representing invariants, and a predicate over X×Y is just a function from X×Y to Bool. So far so good.

The first example I tried is just a problem of inferring an inductive invariant for a `for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)` loop.

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-fun inv (Int) Bool)
(assert (inv 0))
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (or (> I 10) (not (inv I)) (inv (+ I 1)))))
(check-sat)
```

So far so good, got `sat`. Now just added `(assert (not (inv 15))` and I got `unsat`. I then tried

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-fun inv (Int) Bool)
(assert (inv 0))
(assert (not (inv 15)))
(check-sat)
```

and got `unsat`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, I get `sat` using Z3 (commit 210bca8f456361f696152be909e33a4e8b58607f I believe)

Answer (score 2):

Use the "unstable" branch. 
The "interp" branch is for internal development and the state of this branch can fluctuate.
I get the answer "sat" on your second problem.

A slightly more interesting version of the first problem is:

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-fun inv (Int) Bool)
(assert (inv 0))
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (or (> I 10) (not (inv I)) (inv (+ I 1))))) 
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (inv I) (<= I 11))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

It produces the obvious inductive invariant.
If you replace the last assertion by

```
(assert (forall ((I Int)) (=> (inv I) (<= I 10))))
```

Instead you get a (hard to read) proof.